# Lua: how are tables used as hash key?

Tags: dictionary, hash, lua-table

When a table is being used as a hash key, does it have anything to do with the hex id you get when you print out the table?

For example,

```
obj = {}
print(obj)
```

You might get something like `table: 153CF5A0`. Is this value used in the hashing process of this table?

I noticed that if you create two identical tables that aren't references of each other, they hash to different things:

```
obj1 = {}
obj2 = {}
map = {}

map[obj1] = 'obj1'
map[obj2] = 'obj2'
print(map[obj1]) -- obj1
print(map[obj2]) -- obj2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the memory address of a table is used as a key for hashing when the table is used to index another table. See the [source code](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html#mainposition) (tables are handled in the default case).

Comment: How is the hash function able to differentiate between the memory address of table (153CF5A0), and the integer 153CF5A0?

Comment: @yelq, it does not: it treats collisions of course.